# Find all keywords

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class as follows:

```
public class PropertyResult {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of this class and a string:

```
List<PropertyResult> properties = externalAPI.GetProperties();

List<String> keywords = new List<String> { "A", "B", "C" }
```

Note that a property keywords is something like "A, B, C".

I need to get all properties which have ALL keywords. I was going for:

```
properties = listing.Properties.All(x => keywords.Contains(x.Keywords))
```

The problem is that x.Keywords has all keywords in a string.

Comment: Can you change `Keywords` to be a `List` instead of a comma separated string?

Comment: No ... That comes like that from an external API. I have no control over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Where` + `All` :-

```
var result = properties.Where(x => keywords.All(z => x.Keywords.Contains(z)));
```

[Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y2xjNX)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the sets contain different numbers of characters. Using my test (see other answer) if the `Keywords` string contains "A,B,C,D" it will get returned. Perhaps that's okay (the OP's question was a little unclear on whether a superset was allowed).

Comment: @CraigW. - No for me OP's question was pretty clear as he said **I need to get all properties which have ALL keywords.** So by latter he meant `List<String> keywords` not vice versa.

Comment: Yes, I also read his original post. The statement you quoted, at least at the time it was written, is open to interpretation. I still maintain it wasn't clear whether an exact set match or a superset was allowed (i.e. are the sets [A,B,C] and [A,B,C,D] == or !=). Given he accepted your answer I expect that for his purposes they should be considered ==, but if someone tries to implement your solution in cases where a superset is not allowed they would get incorrect results.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
List<PropertyResult> properties = new List<PropertyResult>();

List<String> keywords = new List<String> { "A", "B", "C" };

properties.Add(new PropertyResult() { Id = 1, Keywords = "A,B,C" });
properties.Add(new PropertyResult() { Id = 1, Keywords = "A,B,C,D" });
properties.Add(new PropertyResult() { Id = 1, Keywords = "B,C,D" });

var result = properties.Where(p => p.Keywords.Split(',').Except(keywords).Count() == 0);
```

When I run the above in LINQPad `result` is an `IEnumerable<PropertyResult>` with a single entry, the `PropertyResult` that contains "A,B,C" (as you would expect/hope).

If you're not a fan of LINQPad, here's a .NET Fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/wKAJfb).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to break apart the keyword string so you'll have the individual keywords, and then compare that collection to the one you have. I'm assuming that you don't care about order - a property with the keywords "B,A,C" will match a keyword list of "A,B,C".

```
var keywords = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};
var matches = listing.Properties.Where(
         prop => new HashSet<string>(prop.Keywords.Split(','))
                 .SetEquals(keywords));
```

What we're doing here is splitting the keywords by string and loading them into a HashSet, which is an efficient data structure for set operations. Then we use the `SetEquals` method to check whether the hashset contains the same elements as your keyword list.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use .Any to go through the array of strings and return `True` if one of the keywords matches the Properties.

```
properties = listing.Properties.Where(x => keywords.Any(a => a[0] == x)).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't even compile. The context variable `x` is of type `PropertyResult` so `a[0] == x` is trying to compare a `char` to a `PropertyResult`.